# Converting char* to string, then assigning to struct member: initialization makes integer from pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I will be receiving data for new users and parsing it using strtok(), which returns a char*. However, I am having trouble assigning the char* to my struct members, which are of the type char[]. I am getting the warning on line 52: Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast. I don't understand why the compiler thinks I am making an integer from a pointer. I thought I was assigning a string (`username`) to a string type (`char username[MAX_USERNAME_LEN + 1]`).

Can someone please elaborate on my error (and perhaps give a suggestion on how to achieve my desired result)? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), bind(), and connect() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h> /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for close() */

#define MAXPENDING 5    /* Maximum outstanding connection requests */
#define MAX_MSGS 25 /* Maximum number of messages a user can have in his/her
               inbox = maximum number of messages a user can have in
               his/her Sent folder */
#define MAX_MSG_LEN 500 /* Maximum message length in characters */
#define MAX_USERS 50    /* Maximum number of users that can exist */
#define SERVER_PORT 8000/* The server port number */
#define MAX_RCV_LEN 2048    /* Buffer size in bytes for messages received by socket */
#define MAX_USERNAME_LEN 32
#define MAX_PASSWORD_LEN 32


struct user{
    char username[MAX_USERNAME_LEN + 1];
    char password[MAX_PASSWORD_LEN + 1];
};

/* Array of users */
struct user users[MAX_USERS];
int numberOfUsers;

int main(void) {
    /* THIS WORKS */
    struct user alice = { .username = "alice", .password = "1234"};
    users[0] = alice;
    numberOfUsers ++;

    /* 
     * I will be receiving data for new users and parsing it using
     * strtok(), which returns a char*, so this is why I hoped to be
     * able to add new users in the following manner: */
    char recvBuffer[MAX_RCV_LEN + 1] = "03::billy::1234::";
    char* opCodePtr = strtok(recvBuffer, "::");
    char* usernamePtr = strtok(NULL, "::");
    char* passwordPtr = strtok(NULL, "::");

    char username[MAX_USERNAME_LEN + 1];
    strncpy(username, usernamePtr, MAX_USERNAME_LEN);

    char password[MAX_PASSWORD_LEN + 1];
    strncpy(password, passwordPtr, MAX_PASSWORD_LEN);

    /* The following line gives me the Warning: initialization makes
       integer from pointer without a cast */
    struct user newUser = {.username = username, .password = password};
    users[numberOfUsers] = newUser;
    numberOfUsers ++;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i ++)
        printf("USER = %s, PASS = %s\n", users[i].username, users[i].password);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
USER = alice, PASS = 1234
USER = �, PASS = p
```

Comment: Thanks, @John3136. Using `strncpy(users[numberOfUsers].username, usernamePtr, MAX_USERNAME_LEN);
     strncpy(users[numberOfUsers].password, passwordPtr, MAX_PASSWORD_LEN);` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`username` is a pointer to some chars somewhere, `.username` is an array of chars. You can't just populate the array via `array = pointer`. You need to do something like `strncpy(array, pointer, size)`.

Note that I don't know how safe it is to use the `char*`'s returned by `strtok` as `strtok` modifies the string as it tokenises, so I suspect the results you get from saving up all the tokens may not actually end up being what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, You have incremented the `numberOfUsers` twice i.e in the line numbers 33,54. And you are printing the `username` and `password` based on the `numberOfUsers` in the for loop so an additional print is made which is holding the garbage values. So, remove one of them based on the appropriate context.

Answer (score 0):

John is correct. Remember that an array name is the address of the first element in it, so, using it as an rvalue yields the address (not the value) of the first element, that is, an integer, which you are using to initialize the arrays in the struct.